"Creating TIFF with legacy Deflate codec identifier" warning when converting from DjVu to PDF
When converting to PDF with ddjvu:
ddjvu -format=pdf input.djvu output.pdf

there is a warning:

TIFFWriteDirectorySec: Warning, Creating TIFF with legacy Deflate codec identifier, COMPRESSION_ADOBE_DEFLATE is more widely supported.

But when I accomply -format=pdf with -quality or -mode, there is no such a warning.
ddjvu -format=pdf -quality=100 input.djvu output.pdf

ddjvu -format=pdf -mode=black  input.djvu output.pdf

Why is that?

-quality= with a number implies lossy jpeg compression. "Deflate" is not jpeg, so the warning is not needed.
-mode=black probably just implies "256-indexed; greyscale", and would probably default to something not requiring a warning (like RLE etc.). This could also mean actually black (as in 1 color bitmap). I think this would be CCITT?
The odd thing is that the manual says "Specifying this option [-quality=deflate] is not necessary for PDF files because this is the default behavior." Perhaps the warning is saying that default deflate is not the adobe one. The manual does say that "Images that cannot be encoded using [..] TIFF/G4 [...] will be [...] DEFLATE compression if available [otherwise packbits]." So somewhere the encoder is deciding what to do and warning about a potential interoperability issue.
https://djvu.sourceforge.net/doc/man/ddjvu.html

Many thanks, Yorik. Could you explain, do I need to use quality=150 or instead not using the -quality option at all to have as high quality as possible?

150 is the best quality possible for JPEG according to the documentation. Jpeg is a lossy format, and lossy means quality reduction. Obviously jpeg can be pretty good regarding quality, but it trades quality for file size. This appears to be jpeg compression used in a TIFF file format. Deflate is better as it is not a lossy format. However if file size matters, you might try 80 or 90 and compare that file with a file using deflate.

BTW you might try using -quality=COMPRESSION_ADOBE_DEFLATE. It might not work but the warning may be telling you indirectly that that is a way to specify it. worth a try

So, I haven't looked at all at outputs. The documentation supports you in that a deflate-compressd-TIFF is default for PDF, but I believe the -quality=100 option would create a jpeg-compressed-TIFF. So not a "jpeg file" (i.e.JFIF)

Ah. I thought that was clear in the documentation under format.
